# Browserify babelify ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, babeljs, browserify

Hi I am trying to us babelify and browserify to bundle my js files. Though once I add the keyword import into the file I get the following error
`export * from '@firebase/auth'; ^ ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'`
I have tried a couple solutions but none has worked
these are my files if anyone can help I would appreciate greatly

**index.js**

```
var babelify = require("babelify");
browserify("index.js").transform(babelify, 
    {
        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"], 
        sourceMaps: true, 
        global: true, 
    });
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut } from "firebase/auth";
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/Project-Template/images/site_Icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Project-Template/style/userAuth.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
    <script src="/Project-Template/bundle.js"></script>

</head>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "project-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "project temp",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Pm",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babelify": "^10.0.0"
  }
}
```

**babel.config.json**

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
  
}
```

I tried adding this code to index.js but it did not work. Plus I'm not sure how to use it
`browserify.transform("babelify",  { presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],  sourceMaps: true,  global: true,  ignore: [/\/node_modules\/(?!your module folder\/)/] }).bundle()`